# How can we convert YYYYWWD format date into normal date format YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: mainframe, jcl, syncsort

How can we convert `YYYYWWD` format date into normal date format `YYYY-MM-DD` using Syncsort?

Comment: Im not saying it can't be done (I don't know enough about SYNCSORT), but why couldn't the program that builds the file output the proper format for the date?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are out of luck. Syncsort has the same features as DF/Sort and according to this - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.icea100/ice2ca_DFSORT_data_formats.htm - Df/sort does not recognise a YYYYWWD date format. It may be possible however to so the maths yourself with Syncsort, but I can;t see any way to do this.

YYYYWWD is a non-standard date format, so this is not really surprising. The best solution (if you cannot get the data in the correct format initially) would be to process the data with REXX before sorting it, if the volumes of data allows this.

Unless, of course, this is a 'homework' question and you have to use Syncsort? (which would imply that it is possible)